# error in attaching temporary to a reference to const

Tags: c++, reference, constants, temporary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [typedef and containers of const pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148769/typedef-and-containers-of-const-pointers)

Why is the code emitting an error?

```
int main()
{
  //test code
  typedef int& Ref_to_int;
  const Ref_to_int ref = 10; 
}
```

The error is:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from a temporary of type ‘int’

I read the post on [prolonging the lifetime of temporaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670137/prolonging-the-lifetime-of-temporaries) which says that temporaries can be bound to references to const. Then why is my code not getting compiled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the type of `ref` is actually `reference to int` and not `const reference to int`. The const qualifier is ignored.

$8.3.2 says

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef (7.1.3) or of a template type argument (14.3), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

`const Ref_to_int ref;` is equivalent to `int& const ref;` and not `const int& ref`.

Comment: Or in another word, a `typedef` is not a simple text replacement... and `const` should be put *after* what they qualify for humans not to forget it.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing `const` with a typedef doesn't work the way you're thinking; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148769/typedef-and-containers-of-const-pointers) for more info. These two lines are equivalent:

```
const Ref_to_int ref;
int& const ref;
```

You're looking for:

```
const int& ref;
```

One way to fix it is to include it in the typedef itself (although you should probably rename it then):

```
typedef const int& Ref_to_int;
```

Comment: I think this question is for all intents and purposes a duplicate of the one you mentioned.

Comment: @Chris Good point; the distinction between pointers and references doesn't really matter

Answer (score 0):

You can't add additional specifiers to a `typedef`. It doesn't work like a macro.

Your code is effectively

```
int& const ref = 10;  // error
```

which isn't valid.